# How to extend block.block.* schema configuration file

Tags: 8, configuration

Someone know how to exend this schema located in block module in core, to add a new data type in mapping from my custom module?

The point is that I need to add a Boolean field for all the blocks in the block configuration page and store this value (0 or 1) in all the block configuration files, but the problem I have is when I import the configuration for those blocks that does not  import the boolean field.

**I guess I'm missing declare a "data type" for this boolean field.**

```
    block.block.*:
      type: config_entity
      label: 'Block'
      mapping:
        id:
          type: string
          label: 'ID'
        theme:
          type: string
          label: 'Theme'
        region:
          type: string
          label: 'Region'
        weight:
          type: integer
          label: 'Weight'
        provider:
          type: string
          label: 'Provider'
        plugin:
          type: string
          label: 'Plugin'
        settings:
          type: block.settings.[%parent.plugin]
        visibility:
          type: sequence
          label: 'Visibility Conditions'
          sequence:
            type: condition.plugin.[id]
            label: 'Visibility Condition'
```

I want to add this

```
   mapping:
    hide_for_campaign:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Blocks hidden in campaign page'
```

Comment: Can't you store the value in a field on your custom block type?

Comment: The point is that I need to add a Boolean field for all the blocks in the block configuration page and store this value (0 or 1) in all the block configuration files, but the problem I have is when I import the configuration for those blocks that does not  import the boolean field. I improved the description on top.

Comment: I think in your case your could benefit from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info/8.5.x

Comment: mmm i dont know it says "Provides custom base field definitions for a content entity type." It can be useful for content entities, not Config entities, i need add it for block entity.

Comment: The answer is to use the `ThirdPartySettingsInterface` interface, which allows to add/save custom configuration for configuration entities. Thank you! More info are available on 
https://www.heididev.com/how-alter-configuration-entity-data-drupal-8-or-add-additional-data-configuration-entities.